# How can I make new wireless connections use a VPN by default?

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I check this box every time I connect to a new wireless network:

[image: Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection]

How can I make it enabled by default for new connections?

Comment: Did you ever do anything with below answer? (just curious)

Comment: No, I've just been checking it manually. I don't connect to many new networks, and those that I do often have captive portals that I'd have to disable the VPN for anyway.

Answer (score 1):

All of the following:

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case vpn
gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case wifi
gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case conn
```

give nothing useful, so 2 possibilities left:

1. You do a feature-request at Canonical (24,557 reputation, 28 gold 118 silver and 248 bronze badges *should* carry *some* weight...)
2. I create a script that creates a script that sets it up for you... (might take a while as I'm writing an automated system backup now...)

Comment: Writing it as an answer as these are much more readable. will convert to comment if you downvote...